# Should I use one mapping table for multiple data-type tables, or create different mapping tables for each data-type?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

At the moment I have one huge tag table and I use mapping table to map tags with another mapping table to map with data table. The reason I added another mapping-to-data table is that I have multiple different data tables.

**There are two data tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `photo` varchar(45) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `website_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Both of them I use in my search fields, and they should be linked to one TAG list table

**There's tag table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And what I do - I use two more tables to map data tables with tags:

**Two mapping tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_map_type` (
  `tmtid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `type` enum('cars_list','website_list') NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tmtid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_map` (
  `tmid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `map_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tmid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `tags_map`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tag_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`tag_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `map_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`map_type_id`) REFERENCES `tags_map_type` (`tmtid`)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And table `tags_map_type` then links either to `cars_list` or to `website_list`

**QUESTION:**

How can I make a `foreign key` to link `tags_map_type` to one of the list tables?

Or should I use another mapping table for each `cars_list`, `website_list`, `some_other_list` table?

Which way is correct and best to use?

Comment: I think that your model is, unusual...  Are you attempting to make `tags_map_type.type_id` associate to `cars_list.id` ***or*** `website_list`, depending on the value in `tags_map_type.type`?  That's not possible.  How about doing it the other way around?   The two lists have a `tagable_entity_id` pointing to a `tagable_entity` table?  Then the `tags_map` also points to the `tagable_entity` table?  *(Similar to an OO model of; a `tagable_entity` being the parent class, each `list` being a sub-class.)*

Comment: @MatBailie And linking `taggable_entity_id` from `_list` tables to it's id in `tagable_entity` table? Then each time new row is added to any of the `_list` tables, first new `tagable_entity` should be inserted, right?

Comment: I would populate the `taggable_entity` table first, then the list table.  That way the IDs will exist, and you won't breach any foreign key constraints.